# unable to use handler, getting looper.prepare error

Tags: android, handler, looper

I was trying to use handler in onPageFinished method of onCreateView method of PlanetFragment class. But I am getting looper.prepare() error. Please help. And also please tell if there is some better method to use progressbar.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

static Handler progressBarHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                getActivity().getPackageName());

        final WebView webview = ((WebView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.image));

        final ProgressBar progressbar = ((ProgressBar) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.progressbar));

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final PlanetFragment activity = this;

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);// hide the webview that will
                                                // display your dialog
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    private int progressBarStatus = 0;

                    private int fileSize;

                    public void run() {
                        progressBarHandler = new Handler();
                        while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                            // process some tasks
                            progressBarStatus = doWork();

                            // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // Update the progress bar
                            progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    progressbar
                                            .setProgress(progressBarStatus);

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        // ok, file is downloaded,
                        if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                            // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    private int doWork() {
                        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

                            fileSize++;

                            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                                return 10;
                            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                                return 20;
                            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                                return 30;
                            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                                return 40;
                            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                                return 50;
                            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                                return 60;
                            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                                return 70;
                            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                                return 80;
                            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                                return 90;
                            }

                        }

                        return 100;

                    }
                }).start();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBarHandler = new Handler();
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('icon-anon')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('cse_x')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_search')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer_random_button')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('mw-mf-page-left')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('mw-mf-viewport')[0].style.display=\"none\";");

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Code here will run in UI thread
                    }
                },1000);

                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // you might need this
                view.bringToFront();
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(planet);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I also tried this but its also giving same error      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postdelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
         }
     },1000);

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **handler** in Activity

just initialize the **Handler** in **onCreate** method of activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       progressBarHandler = new Handler();
   // rest of your code
```

and remove the initialization in Fragment class as it is already initialized in Activity . Just Use **progressBarHandler** in Fragment Class and it will work fine.